# Microsoft Graph SharePoint access items (read/write)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am attempting to create a new `list item` in SharePoint Online using the [[beta] Microsoft Graph endpoint](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/listitem_create). The goal is to call Microsoft Graph from an Outlook Add-in but the problem persists on Postman.

When I call the endpoint as per the documentation I get the following error message:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "unauthenticated",
        "message": "The caller is not authenticated.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "bb094f39-71c9-4c7d-9d9b-913cc9622baf",
            "date": "2017-08-08T11:32:02"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using ADAL JS to fetch the authentication token and I initialized my `AuthenticationContext` with my `tenantID`. My app has the following permissions: `offline_access, Sites.Read.All, Sites.ReadWrite.All, User.Read`

**2nd Edit - more details on readItem**
I use the `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items` endpoint with the `{site-id}` of my desired site from `/sites` and the `{list-id}` of the list from `/sites/{site-id}/lists` but this is the empty response I get:

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/...",
    "value": []
}
```

If I try to to add `/{item-id}` to my original call to access specific item I receive this response:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "itemNotFound",
        "message": "The specified list was not found",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "6e7ccae3-3aee-4dbb-ae3e-de61250478e0",
            "date": "2017-08-09T13:13:33"
        }
    }
}
```

Which doesn't make sense because I can retrieve valid information about the list if i make the call without `/items/..`

Any and all input appreciated :) I'll gladly provide more code, this is all I deemed relevant and didn't want to overcrowd the post.

Answer (score 0):

might be that you actually don't have an item with that id, since `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/1` works for me.

test the id's you really have by just `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items` and each item returns it's id.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I'm afraid that is not the case, as my second edit details, I call `/items` with the aforementioned results. I am attempting a rebuild on a fresh tenant with a new app with different permissions.

Comment: then what exactly do you try to achieve?

Comment: @KetillAntoníusÁgústsson have you got the solution for this issue?

Comment: @VaibhavBhatia No sorry, we abandoned this back when. I assume this was just an error with the Beta endpoints at the time. I'd recommend you to look at the [pnpjs library](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/) if you're looking for something similar today :)